# Link a Application to handle a file format in file manager Android

Tags: android, file, file-manager

I created a simple file manager that lists all file in the sdcard,

OnClick on file name, i want to open the file in Application that can handle that file format.

How it works?

Just give me a hint to start and i will handle the rest..

thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to do anything for it, other than firing off an `Intent` with the relevant data (i.e. action, mime type etc). It's all covered in the basic [Sending the User to Another App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html) training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, Thanks all @MH

This code is doing all what i wanted to do.

```
                    File file = new File(listOfDocs.get(position).getFilePath());
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    try {
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, 
                            "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: yeah, just have to check for file extension before i set the DataAndType and thats all

Answer (score 0):

i think the most important thing to do that you know its extensions

You can use [FilenameUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) from Apache Commons to do that

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(mFile.getName());
```

when you have extension you can target specific application to open with

Comment: How should i make it open application? and i already have the extension? rather how to open the adobe or text reader on click on file name is requrired

Comment: you can use pathPattern